# Can't open .jnlp file even though I have a JRE installed

Tags: java, macos, file

I have downloaded a .jnlp file, but when opening it with Java Web Start I am greeted with the following message: "To open this Web Start application you need to download the Java Runtime Environment." The OS is macOS 10.15.6.

Running `java -version` in the Terminal outputs

```
java version "13.0.1" 2019-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

So I do, in fact, have a JRE installed. What can I do to open the file?

Answer (score 1):

JNLP refers to the file format defined for Java Webstart technology. Check out https://openwebstart.com/:

*Java Web Start (JWS) was deprecated in Java 9, and starting with Java 11, Oracle removed JWS from their JDK distributions.*
[...]
*This is why we decided to create OpenWebStart, an open source reimplementation of the Java Web Start technology.*

You will either have to downgrade your Java installation or add OpenWebStart.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue today while running on Windows. The .jnlp file wasn't recognizing the that JRE was installed even with Java Web Start running.

I went ahead and reinstalled JRE 8 and the .jnlp file launched just fine.